# R Shiny - no repeating image in tags$body

Tags: r, shiny

I aim to write a text over an image.
I insert my image in background using tags$body but I don't achieve to avoid its repetition. Does anyone know how to discard this issue ?

Below a simple example:

```
tabPanel(title = 'World',
  tags$body(background = 'globe.png'),
  tags$h5('Hello World'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play around with CSS class `overlay`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
        useShinyjs(),
        tags$img(src="images.jpg", width="100%"),
        div(class="overlay", "Headline",
                             inlineCSS(list(".overlay:before" = c("content: ''", "display: inline-block", "height: 100%", "vertical-align: middle"),
                              ".overlay" = c("text-align: center", "position:absolute", "top:0", "left:0", "right:0", "bottom:0", "z-index:999", "color: red", "font-size: 50px"))))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I used package `shinyjs` to add CSS properties (`inlineCSS`) to "Headline" that enable it to float centered over the picture (which needs to be in subfolder www).